# VM status using PHP SOAP

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am so far able to retrieve the following information about VM from VMWARE Esxi using php SOAP.

> 'name', 'guest.ipAddress', 'guest.guestState', 'runtime.powerState',
>   'config.hardware.numCPU', 'config.hardware.memoryMB'

and here is the code.

```
class soapclientd extends soapclient
{
        public $action = false;

    public function __construct($wsdl, $options = array())
        {
        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    }

        public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
        {
//        echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array ('<ns', '></'), array (PHP_EOL . '<ns', '>'.PHP_EOL.'</'), $request)) . '</pre>';
        $resp = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
                return $resp;
        }

}


$client =  new SoapClient("https://172.16.3.3/sdk/vimService.wsdl", array("trace" => 1, "location"=>"https://172.16.3.3/sdk/"));
try
{
    $request = new stdClass();
    $request->_this = array ('_' => 'ServiceInstance', 'type' => 'ServiceInstance');
    $response = $client->__soapCall('RetrieveServiceContent', array((array)$request));
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
$ret = $response->returnval;

try
{
    $request = new stdClass();
    $request->_this = $ret->sessionManager;
    $request->userName = 'root';
    $request->password = 'xxxx';
    $response = $client->__soapCall('Login', array((array)$request));
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$ss1 = new soapvar(array ('name' => 'FolderTraversalSpec'), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'selectSet', null);
$ss2 = new soapvar(array ('name' => 'DataCenterVMTraversalSpec'), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'selectSet', null);
$a = array ('name' => 'FolderTraversalSpec', 'type' => 'Folder', 'path' => 'childEntity', 'skip' => false, $ss1, $ss2);

$ss = new soapvar(array ('name' => 'FolderTraversalSpec'), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'selectSet', null);
$b = array ('name' => 'DataCenterVMTraversalSpec', 'type' => 'Datacenter', 'path' => 'vmFolder', 'skip' => false, $ss);

$res = null;
try
{
    $request = new stdClass();
    $request->_this = $ret->propertyCollector;
    $request->specSet = array (
        'propSet' => array (
            array ('type' => 'VirtualMachine', 'all' => 0, 'pathSet' => array ('name', 'guest.ipAddress', 'guest.guestState', 'runtime.powerState', 'config.hardware.numCPU', 'config.hardware.memoryMB')),
        ),
        'objectSet' => array (
            'obj' => $ret->rootFolder,
            'skip' => false,
            'selectSet' => array (
                new soapvar($a, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'TraversalSpec'),
                new soapvar($b, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'TraversalSpec'),
                ),
            )
        );
    $res = $client->__soapCall('RetrieveProperties', array((array)$request));
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

print_r($res);
```

the output for the code is something like this for each VM.

```
    [28] => stdClass Object
        (
            [obj] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [_] => 97
                    [type] => VirtualMachine
                )

            [propSet] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => config.hardware.memoryMB
                            [val] => 15996
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => config.hardware.numCPU
                            [val] => 4
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => guest.guestState
                            [val] => notRunning
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => name
                            [val] => 8796-january-Core-3.181
                        )

                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => runtime.powerState
                            [val] => poweredOff
                        )

                )

        )
```

now I would like to extend the retrieval information to VM resource consumption stats like used memory, CPU , network etc.

I tried adding the properties in array but then the code itself is not working so mainly either the name of the properties are wrong or this is not the right way to retrieve those things.

Comment: I have found something , that if I specify 'all' => 1 in specSet then I am able to fetch a plenty of information which I need to parse as per my requirement. But I would like to query only required information.

Answer (score 0):

So,

The entire game is based on the propSet value.

```
    'propSet' => array (
        array ('type' => 'VirtualMachine', 'all' => 0, 'pathSet' => array ('name', 'guest.ipAddress', 'guest.guestState', 'runtime.powerState', 'config.hardware.numCPU', 'config.hardware.memoryMB')),
    )
```

Here if I mention all=1 then I can retrieve literally everything.

But, for filtered things I need to mention the property name in 'pathSet' array.

I fetched all information for the first time using all=1 and now. I have complete list of properties. Base on fetched data I can add more properties.

like 'overallStatus' which should result the 'green' in normal condition.

like the following

```
config.guestFullName => Oracle Linux 4/5/6 (64-bit)
config.uuid => 564d2981-6b15-8a42-b7fc-4e86e7401655
config.version => vmx-08
guest.hostName => Win7-VM
guest.net.macAddress => 00:0c:29:ad:d4:f0
```